# FAIL - Application at context path /sagar could not be started

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

War file deployed but unable to start project.Can someone please help to find the root cause of this issue. below is the error log details -

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9mIT.jpg)

Thanks in advance for help and cooperation.